# Como faço para somar todos os valores de uma coluna PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom é assim eu na minha tabela usuarios, tenho a coluna saldo, como faço somar o saldo de todos os usuários, ou seja o saldo de todos os registos na tabela com PHP?

Obrigado.

Comment: Não cogita fazer isso com o `SUM()` na query ? De todo modo também dá pra atribuir uma variável que vai ficar se auto somando toda vez que passar pelo registro. Algo como `$saldoTotal += $coluna['saldo'];` isso dentro do _loop_ que usou pra construir a tabela.

Comment: Eu não queria usar while. Não tem outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Como tem os dados em um array, dá pra percorrer o mesmo usando uma função `array_map()`, mas acho que não dá pra escapar de um _loop_.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo na resposta?, Obrigado.

Comment: Como está estruturada a tabela e quais dados deseja somar?

Comment: Somar todos os registos da coluna saldo.

Comment: Opá, tá na mão [Ideone](http://ideone.com/JQHL6j).

Comment: é só usar o `SUM()` na `query`

Comment: só depois eu ví que oque você queria era com o php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinha postado uma resposta mas ví que oque você queria era com **PHP**.

> Criei a solução com base no comentário do @William Novak para usar o array_sum com array_map

Para você fazer a soma sem precisar usar um loop você precisa resgatar os saldos e joga-los em um `array`. Depois é só usar o `array_sum`.

```
  <?php

   // este array foi obtido a partir seleção feita no banco de dados
   $saldo = array(0, 20, 30, 40);

   // vamos usar o array_sum para fazer a soma
   $total = array_sum($saldo);

  ?>
```

Mas se o seu array for um array multidimensional com outros dados você pode fazer assim sem loop:

```
  $usuario = array(

    // abaixo temos o id do usuario e o saldo de cada um
    array( "id" => 0, "saldo" => 20),
    array( "id" => 2, "saldo" => 30),
    array( "id" => 3, "saldo" => 40),
    array( "id" => 4, "saldo" => 60),

  );

   // vamos usar o array_sum para fazer a soma

$total = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 

    return $item['saldo']; 

}, $usuario));


 echo $total;

?>
```